# How to detect when Iframe video ends? No API

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, iframe

I have a iframe generated on my site. The src of the iframe is video id from database. I would like to know, how can I detect that the video finishes playing.
My embeded youtube video:

```
echo "<iframe width='50%' height='60%' id='cc' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" . $data_song[0] . "' frameborder='1' allowfullscreen></iframe><br>";
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You must go to frontend area.Look about iframe access and video listeners... Maybe Q is too board.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Since you are using the iframe to stream youtube videos, what you want can be achieved by this,

When Player.Status = 0 that means the video has stopped. I have commented those for you to understand easily.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

 var player;

$(document).ready(function () {
    onYouTubePlayerAPIReady();
});


 function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
    events: {
        'onStateChange': getStatus
       }
    });
 }

 var tag = document.createElement('script');
 tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
 var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    function getStatus() {

    var sStatus;
    sStatus = player.getPlayerState();

      if (sStatus == -1) {}  //Video has not started yet

      else if (sStatus == 0) {  

      // video has stopped. This is the event that you want

     }
     else if (sStatus == 1) { } //Video is playing
     else if (sStatus == 2) {}  //Video is paused
     else if (sStatus == 3) { } //video is buffering 
     else if (sStatus == 5) { } //Video is cued.
   }

  </script>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me..I am generating the `<iframe>` in a php class and I take src from my table. Do you think its better to create the `<iframe>` in javascript?
Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: That FirstTag Things are idiotic. If there is any other content in the page or other javascript in page, this thing won't work :-) This will work if the page contains this video only.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a tag `&lt;video&gt;` is better.

For example:

Your HTML

`<video id="videoplayer">`.

Your JS

`var myvideo = document.getElementById('videoplayer');
myvideo.addEventListener('ended',function() {
    // The video's callback
} ,false);`

Comment: How does this work on **any** video shown in an iframe?

Comment: You can't control a video into an iframe. The `<video>` tag was made for this.

Comment: Okay, then please give an example about how to embed a Youtube video using `<video>`